# HTML/JS Table-Header does not match up to Table-Body

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I've a litte problem diplaying a table correctly.
The table-header ist not consistent with the table-body.
The table date gets displayed in the colums 1/3/5/7, so the odd columns are getting skipped, idk why this happens.

On the following link you can look how the table gets displayed.
[image: how the table looks]

Relevant Code:

HTML-Code:

```
<div id="accreqlist" hidden="true">
      <h1>Accountanfragen Liste</h1>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lm" id="accreqreturnbtn">zurück</button>
        <form id="accreqlist_form">
          <div id=accreq_message class="form__message form__message--error"></div>
         </form>
   <table class="tablelist" id="tblAccList">
      <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Accountanfrage ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>E-Mail</th>
          <th>Mobile</th>
          <th>Action 1</th>
          <th>Action 2</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
   <tbody>
  <!--will get filled through js file-->
   </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
```

JS-Code:

```
function accountRequestlistclicked() {
  $.getJSON("/api/accountRequests").done(handleAccountRequestlistReply);
}

function handleAccountRequestlistReply(reqs) {
  $("#tblAccList tbody").empty();

  for (let req of reqs) {
    addReqToList(req);
  }
}

function addReqToList(req) {
  let id = req["accountRequestId"];

  var newRow = "<tr>";
  newRow += "<td>" + req["accountRequestId"] + "<td>";
  newRow += "<td>" + req["accountRequestName"] + "<td>";
  newRow += "<td>" + req["accountRequestEmail"] + "<td>";
  newRow += "<td>" + req["accountRequestMobile"] + "<td>";
  newRow +=
    "<td> <button id = 'u" +
    req["accountRequestId"] +
    "' onClick='deleteAccRequest(" +
    req["accountRequestId"] +
    ")'> Delete </button> </td>";
  newRow +=
    "<td> <button id = 'u" +
    req["accountRequestId"] +
    "' onClick='createUser(" +
    req["accountRequestId"] +
    ")'> Account erstellen </button> </td>";
  newRow += "</tr>";

  $("#tblAccList tbody").append(newRow);
}

//accreq löschen
function deleteAccRequest(id) {
  var urlstring = "/api/deleteAccountRequest/" + id;
  $.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: urlstring,
    success: deleteReqRespons,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
  });
}
//user erstellen
function createUser(id) {
  var urlstring = "api/createUser/" + id;
  $.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: urlstring,
    success: createUserResponse,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/jsin",
  });
}
```

[image: generated html-code]

Does somebody know how i can fix the table, so that the colums gets displayed correctly?

Im very thankful of every input!

Comment: Look at using Bootstrap to style tables - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/

Comment: can we have a look at the html of the generated table? You will probably end up with some not valid markup in your generated code so start debugging from there

Comment: ok i added it to the post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uff i know what was wrong. I forgot to close the td-tags. so for each data the `</th>` was missing :(( sorry for stealing your time, with this simple problem.
cheers